# Allow only certain strings obtained with autocomplete in input box

Tags: javascript, html

I basically want to make an input box behave like the tags field of StackOverflow, or for example the input field of https://gitignore.io, except that only a single tag is allowed.

Is there any existing library for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Please check select2. This may help you.

https://select2.github.io

Answer (score 0):

These might help

https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Or

http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/

Depends on what Tech you are using.